# If $∩F$ and $∩G$ are disjoint, then for some $A ∈ F$ and $B ∈ G$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

If $∩F$ and $∩G$ are disjoint, then for some $A ∈ F$ and $B ∈ G$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.
Give a proof or counter-example.

I'm like 99 percent the theorem is true, can't seem to prove it. Have tried a few methods, closest I have got is trying to prove the contra-positive. Any help with this problem would be extremely appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked for a counterexample?

Comment: $A=\{1,2,3\}, C=\{3,4,5\}$ in $F$ and $B=\{3,6,7\}, D=\{6\}$ in $G$.

Comment: The above counterexample does not work, since $A \cap D$ and $C \cap D$ are both empty. However, by taking $D = \{1,6,5\}$ I think we are done : although  $A \cap C = \{3\}$ and $B \cap D = \{6\}$ are disjoint, we see that $3 \in A \cap B, 1 \in A \cap D, 3 \in C \cap B$ and $5 \in C \cap D$ are true. So $F = \{A,C\}$ and $G = \{B,D\}$ serves as a counterexample.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, your comment qualifies as an actual answer to the OP.  Please post it as an actual answer, so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Thank you, I have done it below.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample : $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $C = \{3,4,5\}$, $B = \{3,6,7\}$, $D = \{1,5,6\}$ with $F = \{A,C\}$ and $G = \{B,D\}$.

In particular, $3 \in A \cap B$, $3 \in C \cap B$, $5 \in C \cap D$ , $1 \in A \cap D$. However, $\cap F = \{3\}$ and $\cap G  = \{6\}$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Think small: $\mathcal{F}=\bigl\{\{1,2\}\bigr\}$, $\mathcal{G}=\bigl\{\{1\},\{2\}\bigr\}$.

If you don't like that the sets have empty intersection, use $\mathcal{G}=\bigl\{\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\bigr\}$